# Prime number decomposition

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

What is the fastest way to decompose the given number to prime numbers without using calculator?

Example : $$3575$$

What I do is :

$$3575 = 3 \times 10^3 + 5 \times 10^2 + 7 \times 10 + 5 = 3\times5^3\times2^3 + 5^2 \times 2^2 \times 5 + 7 \times 5 \times 2 + 5$$

But now I do not know how to effectively get rid of "$+$".

Comment: This must be divisible by $5^2 = 25$ because divisibility by $25$ depends only on the last two digits (since multiples of $100$ are divisible by $25.$ Dividing it by $25$ you get $143$, and that's easy to factor (it's $11\times 13.$ Notice first that you need not check for divisibility by any prime numbers bigger than $\sqrt{3575}$ since it can have such factors only if it also has smaller prime factors (unless it's prime itself). If you don't know what $\sqrt{3575}$ is and so you don't know whether $25$ is bigger or smaller than $\sqrt{3575}, \text{ then } \ldots\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$look at $3575 = 25\times143$ and observe that $25 < 143$ and concluded that $25$ is less than $\sqrt{3575}$ and $143$ is greater than $\sqrt{3575}.$ After that, you don't have to check $143$ for divisibility by any prime bigger than $\sqrt{143},$ so you only need to go up to $11.\qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By inspection, the final two digits of $75$ means $3575$ is divisible by $25=5^2$. Then the result of dividing out $25$ is $\frac{3500}{25} + \frac{75}{25}=4\times 35+3 = 143=12^2-1 = 11\cdot 13$, giving $3575 = 5^2\cdot11\cdot13$

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way in general is by some "fast" algorithm, whether by computer, or by hand. There is no shortcut in general. There are many [Integer factorization algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization), but the running time is, even for the general number theory sieve, given by
$${\displaystyle O\left(\exp {\sqrt[{3}]{{\frac {64}{9}}b(\log b)^{2}}}\right)}
$$
for a $b$-bit number $n$.
For $n=3575$ we obtain $5^2\cdot 11\cdot 13$. Here we could first try small prime divisors.

Answer (score 2):

$$  3600 - 25 = 60^2 - 5^2 = (60 + 5) (60 - 5) = 65 \cdot 55 $$
Then we see $65 = 5 \cdot 13$ and $55 = 5 \cdot 11$

This is usually called Fermat factorization. Start with the first square larger than the number, see if the difference is a square. If that does not work take the square just larger than that. To save time, we can rule out some squares since the difference cannot be $3 \pmod 4$ or $2 \pmod 4.$ In this case, $61^2 - 3575 = 146 \equiv 2 \pmod 4 $ cannot be a square. We would jump to $62^2 - 3575,$ then $64^2 - 3575.$ However, the first time worked.

If I gave you $9991$ the next larger square would be $10000$ and $10000 - 9991 = 9,$ so $9991 = (100 +3)(100-3) = 103 \cdot 97$